# Universal reference seems not working, compiler take parameters as r-value

Tags: c++

Here's an example:

```
#include "type_traits"
#include "string"

template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    explicit Wrapper(T &&t) : t_(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

    T &Get() { return t_; }

private:
    T t_;
};

int main() {
    std::string s1;
    Wrapper<std::string> w1(std::move(s1));

    std::string s2;
    Wrapper<std::string> w2(s2);
}
```

line `Wrapper<std::string> w1(std::move(s1));` will compile but line `Wrapper<std::string> w2(s2);` will not, the compiler reports an error:

> candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'std::__1::basic_string<char> &&' for 1st argument

For simplicity, I create a `foo` class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo& ) {}
    Foo(Foo&&) {}
};
```

and

```
Foo foo;
Wrapper<Foo> w3(foo);
```

Reports this error:

> no known conversion from 'Foo' to 'Foo &&' for 1st argument

It seems that the "universal reference" doesn't work, the compiler considers the first parameter only as an rvalue reference instead.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor `Wrapper::Wrapper` is not template, the parameter is just not declared as [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references). Given `Wrapper<std::string>`, `Wrapper::Wrapper` always takes parameter as rvalue-reference, i.e. `std::string&&`.

> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same function template:

You can make the constructor template to declare the parameter as forwarding reference. e.g.

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    template <typename X>
    explicit Wrapper(X &&t) : t_(std::forward<X>(t)) {}

    T &Get() { return t_; }

private:
    T t_;
};
```

Comment: Any way to force `T` and `X` the same type? In case a wrong type of `X` is passed but `T` just has a correspondence constructor?

Comment: `{ static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,X>); }` or something like that

Comment: @psionic12  IF they weren't the same wouldn't the compiler error just move to the std::forward bit where it tries to call the t_ constructor?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah for example, `Wrapper<Foo> w3(bar);`, if `Foo` happens to have a constructor which can take a `Bar` type, it will compile, but it is not what I want.